# Size of mountain bike

Tags: mountain-bike, size

I am 180 cm tall and I recently bought a Talon 3, with large frame and tire 29 through the website. I searched and I found that large frame is good for me. When I wanted to pick it up, I found it seems large for me and when I seat, my toes just touch the ground. Can I know if it is ok and I should replace it with another bike? I am new and I am not familiar how large my bike should be and what tire size is perfect.

Thanks

Comment: Toes touching the ground (or not) has little to do with how a bike fits. There are many considerations in bike fit and there are more when considering a mountain bike vs a road bike. At the very least, the cockpit length needs to be right and you need to be able to adjust the height and position of the saddle to facilitate pedaling. There is no perfect tires size.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you mean that it is ok that my toes just touch the ground? Based on what I have watched, legs are straight when pedaling, but I did not know that before and now, I do not get used to it. I am just wondering if it is ok

Comment: I'm saying that toes touching or not touching the ground doesn't say much about the fit. On a long-travel frame with a very steep seat angle, you might not be able to touch at all if the rear shock is locked out. There are so many facets to this and they all have to considered together, ideally by a professional. Your bike should have someone on-hand who can help

Comment: As a rule of thumb, when sitting on the saddle, if you place your heel on the pedal the leg should be fully extended. But usually the length (“reach”) of the bike is much more important because seat height can be adjusted in a wide range (you can usually easily go up or down 10cm).

Comment: Have you tried to lower the seat height. Toes just touching the ground is correct for road use, but for offroad MTBing by a novice, a lower seat height might be better to start with.

Answer (score 2):

as the comments have said. It is good to have your legs able to fully extend when your pedal is at its lowest point. It makes for easier pedaling, I am about your size and I also have a 29in mountain bike. The bike is worth keeping, an easier way to get on would be to step over the frame and as you start pedaling slide onto the seat.

Answer (score 2):

You could start with the manufacturer size recommendations.
Smth like this https://www.giant-bicycles.com/ru/talon-3-2021 .

After some rides try to be aware about body sensations.

For example, I’ve realized that I prefer  to be bended more to to  the steering bar even that frame size fits my heigh. So later I’ve bought a little longer stem and it was fine )

So if you’ve bought the bike and feel uncomfortable try to reach out local bike shop or repair and ask guys there. They could help for sure. There are plenty of options to finetune posture even on existing bike )